# How to position the camera so that the given world coordinate is projected on the given screen position

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js, cesiumjs, babylonjs

I want the camera to be positioned so that the center of the object is rendered at the given pixel coordinates( for example (10, 20)) of the screen.

The center of the object is given in the world coordinate system.
Maybe someone can give me a hint on how to solve it.

Comment: Is this a Cesium question? Your self-answer below looks like Cesium code.  I think the Unity3D, ThreeJS, and BabylonJS tags should be removed if that's the case.

Comment: Logic would be the same for Threejs, Unity3D, BabylonJS

Answer (score 0):

solved as below

```
const { BoundingSphere, Cartesian2, Cartesian3, Matrix4 } = window.Cesium;

let viewer;
let center;

// from threejs Ray.closestPointToPoint
function closestPointToPoint(ray, point, target) {
    Cartesian3.subtract(point, ray.origin, target);

    const directionDistance = Cartesian3.dot(target, ray.direction);

    if (directionDistance < 0) {
        return Cartesian3.clone(ray.origin, target);
    }

    Cartesian3.clone(ray.origin, target);

    target.x += ray.direction.x * directionDistance;
    target.y += ray.direction.y * directionDistance;
    target.z += ray.direction.z * directionDistance;

    return target;
}

function setCamera(targetWorld, targetScreenPosition) {
    const camera = viewer.camera;

    camera.lookAt(targetWorld, new Cartesian3(0, 0, 10));
    camera.lookAtTransform(Matrix4.IDENTITY);

    const ray = camera.getPickRay(targetScreenPosition);

    const target = closestPointToPoint(ray, center, new Cartesian3());

    Cartesian3.subtract(target, center, target);

    const newPosition = Cartesian3.subtract(camera.position, target, new Cartesian3());

    camera.position = newPosition;
}

Sandcastle.addToolbarButton("Move left = 1 / 4", function () {
    const width = viewer._element.offsetWidth;
    const height = viewer._element.offsetHeight;

    const targetPixel = new Cartesian2(width / 4, height / 2);

    setCamera(center, targetPixel);
});

function main() {
    viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

    center = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-114.0, 40.0, 3.0);

    const r = new Cartesian3(1, 1, 1);

    viewer.entities.add({
        name: "Blue ellipsoid",
        position: center,
        ellipsoid: {
            radii: r,
            material: Cesium.Color.BLUE
        }
    });

    viewer.camera.flyToBoundingSphere(new BoundingSphere(center, 10));
}

main();
```